# Cannot view BO reports query

Tags: business-objects

I cannot view the query of a BO report. Whenever I try to edit query the button is dimmed. This report was build externally. Is there any way I could retrieve the query?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you're using BusinessObject BI4 and Web Intelligence.

You will need the following rights to view the SQL statement (assuming that the source is a relational database):

- Application Right, Web Intelligence: `Query script - enable viewing (SQL , MDX...)`
- Content Right, Web Intelligence: `View SQL`

Have a look at the [BusinessObjects Administrator's Guide](http://help.sap.com/bobip?current=pcat_analytics&show_children=false#section4) for more information regarding the different types of rights and how to assign them.